# a certain website doesn't respond in Opera and Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I can't access one particular website (namely **dictionary.cambridge.org**) on my laptop. It was working fine yesterday but Chrome stopped displaying it in the evening. I thought website's servers were down so didn't pay much attention to it. Had tried to access it this morning but still have no luck.

Error description on both browsers I use is identical: site didn't send any data. (Chrome error message: This page isn’t working dictionary.cambridge.org didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE)

Other details and what I've tried already:

- Can't open it on neither Chrome nor Opera browser, but it does *work on Firefox*;
- Cleared cache on Chrome;
- Tried to open it using Opera's built-in VPN;
- I can access cambridge.org and bookshelf.cambridge.org;
- The problems doesn't seem to be related to my network - I can open the website on my phone and on my second laptop that are connected to the same WiFi network;
- I've restarted the system twice. Also I shutted the laptop down and turned it on again. It all didn't help;
- I tried restarting network manager in a console;
- I have tried reconnecting to WiFi;
- I have tried to connect it to another WiFi using my mobile phone as a hotspot;
- I pinged dictionary.cambridge.org, the result was 100% packet loss (mtr --report dictionary.cambridge.org shows the same thing);
- I noticed that Chrome and Opera's address line specifies that the website doesn't use https ("Your connection to this site is not secure") but it does in Firefox;
- I don't use any ad blockers (except Opera Ad Block which is built-in).

My os is Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS.

I would be grateful for any help.

Comment: it looks like this is a browser spesific problem https://forums.opera.com/topic/32731/loading-page-error-at-cambridge-dictionary

Comment: On my Ubuntu 20.04, it works on Firefox, but not on Chromium and Falkon browsers. I tried it on my Wind*ws VM, it works both on Chrome and IE. An interesting situation but I believe the issue is not about Ubuntu. There might be a certificate incompatability issue.

Comment: okay, thank you!

Comment: update: the website is now accessible on Chrome and Opera; the problem didn't lie in Ubuntu's operation.